# react native - firebase auth, sending reset password removes google sign-in method

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

sending a password reset mail to user and resetting password from the link actually REMOVES Google Sign-in method if user has it connected, im using react-native-firebase/auth module for authentication actions.
But the real problem is, even if i send the reset password email from the firebase console itself does the same thing.

I tried to do a workaround after discovering this issue, with adding both google sign-in and email/password methods on register but it doesn't really matter, this always happens.

to reproduce, register a user to your app using google sign-in method & you can send a reset password mail from the authentication page's users panel itself.